# Reverse Proxy vs ServicePartitionClient (for HTTP) in Azure ServiceFabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am interested in why we might use one over the other, i.e. the pros and cons of these approaches.

From what I understood both provide fault-handling and Endpoint Resolution. My assumption is to use ReverseProxy for external clients (outside the cluster) and ServicePartitionClient within a cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reverse proxy works on the *service side*, as a gateway that routes Http requests to other services running inside the cluster. Reverse proxy users can be inside or outside the cluster.

**Pro**: Can be accessed by anyone who understands Http.

**Con**: Restricted to Http. Requires intimate knowledge about service name and partitioning strategy at the caller side.

The partition client runs *client side*, to call services. Depending on the underlying communication technology implemented by `TCommunicationClient`, partition clients can be used inside or outside the cluster. (it's not restricted to Service Remoting)
You could write code that uses the partition client to call the reverse proxy with retry support.

**Pro**: Can be accessed by anyone who has the `TCommunicationClient`.

**Con**: Requires intimate knowledge about service name and partitioning strategy at the caller side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is a warning in Reverse Proxy documentation that states: "When you configure the reverse proxy's port in Load Balancer, all microservices in the cluster that expose an HTTP endpoint are addressable from outside the cluster." Is there a way to avoid this, as all my microservices are exposed over HTTP, but I don't want them to be access from outside. Also, is this not a security risk?